# Django: How to switch relations between two objects

Tags: python, django, database

I am having issues updating a website I run. Essentially, the users on the website cannot be used anymore, so people have to create new accounts. However, users have ManyToMany relations with other tables in the database, and I want to be able to move the relations from the old users to the new ones.

Is there any good way to do this in Django or directly in the database? I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a management command framework for this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

This should live in PROJECT/APPNAME/management/commands/

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


#The class must be named Command, and subclass BaseCommand
class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "fix users relations"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("fixing users begin")

        for user in User.objects.all():
            ...user fix code...

        self.stdout.write("fix users complete")
```